# Ruby + ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

Установил на Ubuntu, `gem install geoip`, но при `require 'geoip'`выдает ошибку

> no such file load -- geoip ( LoadError)

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Почитать документацию?

Comment: как ставил ruby?

Comment: geoip без ошибок установился? Или может быть он вообще не установился?

Comment: @KryDos: или вовсе не устанавливался?

Comment: geoip нормально установился, версия 1.2.1

Comment: Странно как-то. А другие модули(любые) нормально подключаются? 
Если да, то покажите пожалуйста вывод команды

gem list | grep -i 'geoip'  ;)

Comment: gem list | grep -i 'geoip' выдает geoip (1.2.1)
попробовал подключить модули из списка локальных, выдает такую же ошибку: no such file load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что интерпретатор ruby не знает, что нужно использовать gem'ы

Запускайте скрипт вот так:

```
ruby -rubygems ваш_скрипт.rb
```

Либо, чтобы постоянно не писать опцию **-rubygems** сделайте так:

```
export RUBYOPT="rubygems"
```

Comment: не помогло

Answer (score 3):

Перед подключением каких-нибудь гемов подключите rubygems.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'geoip'
require 'anything_you_want'
```

Comment: А когда свалилось в консоль тоже написало "не помогло"?

Comment: Дополните вопрос полным хэдэром вашего скрипта, вплоть до окончания 'require', добавьте полный лог того как вы запускате скрипт, и что выводит.

Comment: скрипт: 
require 'geoip'
запускаю:
ruby hw.rb
вывод:
hw.rb:1:in 'require': no such file to load -- geoip (LoadError) from hw.rb:1: in '<main>'

Comment: а require `'rubygems'` где?

Comment: c require 'rubygems' выдает  hw.rb:2:in 'require': no such file to load -- geoip (LoadError) from hw.rb:2: in '<main>'

Comment: @suv121, где лежать gem'ы? Может GEM_PATH нужно указать...

Comment: а где нужно указать?

Comment: @suv121, можно попробовать в .bashrc дописать 

export GEM_PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.9(версия руби)/

хотя у Вас путь может быть другой

И на всякий случай перезапустить командную строку. Просто закрыть и открыть окно.

Comment: спасибо! помогло